# Unable to Add Lambda Function with AWS SecretManager in Terraform

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws, aws-secrets-manager

I am seeing below error when trying to add Lambda with Secret Manager for rotation -

- Created Secret Manager
- Added Secret Versions
- Created Lambda
- Create Role and Inline Policy for Lambda
- Trying to add secret rotation mechanism

```
    aws_secretsmanager_secret_rotation.example: Still creating... [50s elapsed]
    │ Error: error enabling Secrets Manager Secret "" rotation: AccessDeniedException: Secrets Manager cannot invoke the specified Lambda function. Ensure that the function policy grants access to the principal secretsmanager.amazonaws.com.
    │       status code: 400, request id: 21505edf-635a-4a37-ac38-a9b3faf6a0e0
    │
    │   with aws_secretsmanager_secret_rotation.example,
    │   on secret-manager.tf line 26, in resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_rotation" "example":
    │   26: resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_rotation" "example" {
```

My Lambda Role/Policy Definition are as below -

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda" {
  name = "${local.resource_short_prefix}-role"
  permissions_boundary = "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:policy/permission-boundary"


  assume_role_policy = jsonencode( {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": [
          "lambda.amazonaws.com"          ]
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
)

inline_policy {
    name = "${local.resource_short_prefix}-policy"
    
    policy = jsonencode( 
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
          {
            "Action": [
              "secretsmanager:PutSecretValue",
              "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
              "secretsmanager:Describe*",
              "secretsmanager:Get*",
              "secretsmanager:List*" 
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:*:*:secret:*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
          },
          {
            "Action": "secretsmanager:GetRandomPassword",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
          },
          {
            "Action": [
              "logs:CreateLogStream",
              "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:*:*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
          },
          {
            "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:*:*:*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
          }
        ]
      }
    )
  }


}
```

I dont know what else I am missing here?

Added the Lambda permission as well -

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_secretmanager" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromSecretManager"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambda.function_name
  principal     = "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_secretsmanager_secret.db_creds.arn
  source_account = "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}"
 
}
```

Comment: *"Ensure that the function policy grants access to the principal secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"* Probably using [aws_lambda_permission](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_permission)

Comment: @luke2302 Pardon my ignorance, Where do I have to add that, can you please point.

Comment: That is simply another resource you need to create alongside the role and the lambda, etc.

Comment: The code you posted gives Lambda access to Secrets Manager. The error is saying you need to modify the Lambda function's permissions so Secrets Manager can call it, which is like the reverse of what you have done so far. You need to create an [aws_lambda_permission](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_permission) policy attached to the function that allows Secrets Manager to call it.

Comment: Added but NO luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. The problem is that you need to give an external source permission access to the Lambda function. This is an example to allow any secret (configurable to constrain this) to have access to your Lambda function.

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "example_lambda_permission" {
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.your_function.function_name
  principal     = "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
}
```

You can have a look to the Terraform documentation for better understanding and configuration: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_permission